# Should you localise storyboard?

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard

I'm wondering, should I localise the storyboard? What are your opinions?

I only have text on the storyboard, and I feel like it's a lot better to create outlets for each label / object needed to be localised and then change it based on the localisable.strings.

Then again, when adding a localisation, storyboard is checked, so I feel like there's a reason for it.

Sorry for the general question, but I felt like this is the best place to ask it.

Comment: what you mean localise?

Comment: App localisation (translating to other languages).

Comment: second one is correct: **it's a lot better to create outlets for each label / object needed to be localised**